# Kotlins AndroidX ViewModelProviders Error

Tags: android, viewmodel, androidx, android-jetpack

The androidx ViewModelProvider is not allowing "this" as a valid argument even though it is an activity

```
private fun initializeUI(){
val factory = InjectorUtils.provideQuotesViewModelFactory()

    val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,factory).get(QuotesViewModel::class.java)

}
```

Comment: Are you using an `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity` or some other activity subclass?

Comment: I tried using AppCompatActivity, but I changed it to Activity, it's still not working.

Comment: Did you try `this@yourActivityName` ?